# Что такое cid в структуре веб страницы

Tags: html, ajax

Я делаю приложение на андроиде и хочу при помощи AJAX выдрать данные с выпадающего меню.
В консоли хрома страница, на которую идет запрос при клике содержит в конце адреса
      `.xhtml?cid=5`

Удаляю этот параметр и снова отправляю запрос — ничего не работает, респонс с ошибкой. 

 Каждый раз эта переменная различной величины.

 Как узнать какое значение нужно выбрать?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41890/discussion-on-question-by-alex---cid----).

Answer (score 2):

Значит там есть простенькая защита от ботов. Либо это значащая переменная, которая индифицирует подменю например. Такие вещи делаются роботами - которые, например раз в час запускаются, выдирают эти данные, и ложат тебе на сервер.

Попробуй сделать так - послать сначала запрос на страницу, в которой содержится выпадающее меню, или ссылка с этим параметром. Выдри ссылку - распарсь например регуляркой. И затем уже делай запрос на URL который ты захватил.

Но такой способ плох тем - что страницы не всегда могут быть доступны и не всегда могут выдать тебе корректный ответ + к тому что ты не можешь контролировать время запроса - мало ли чужой сервер тормозит.

Comment: Я так уже делал, не помогает. Страница на которой лежит это меню допустим с cid=1, а при нажатии на нужный мне элемент cid уже другой, причем с каждым кликом разный

Comment: Значит там ещё и куки отправляются. Попробуй в фаербаге выбрать в выпадающем меню у запроса опцию "Копировать как curl" - в консоли сервера затем выполни, получишь что нужно успешно. Затем методом исключения curl-параметров выяснишь, чего тебе не хватает для успеха - скорее всего кук. Может быть доп-заголовки.

Comment: Спасибо, я попробую

Comment: Либо я дурак, либо лыжи не едут) в скопированном cURL точно такие же хедеры что и у меня в запросе

Answer (score 0):

Как сообщил @Sergey CID это conversation ID. Он не успевает изменяться при клике, поэтому дерем этот параметр со страницы, с которой делаем клик и вуаля. В XHR отображается желаемый результат